# wowza rest api to php script

Tags: php, api, rest, wowza

im new to php and wowza and was wondering if anyone can point me to a tutorial on how to use this wowza curl api with php? ive tried searching but cant find the answer anywhere so i came here. what im trying to achive is run this curl via php from a remote computer

this is one of the curl id like to convert to php script however i cant seem to find where or how i should start

```
curl -X POST --header 'Accept:application/json; charset=utf-8' --header 'Content-type:application/json; charset=utf-8' http://localhost:8087/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/vhosts/_defaultVHost_/applications/testlive -d'
{
   "restURI": "http://localhost:8087/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/vhosts/_defaultVHost_/applications/testlive",
   "name": "testlive",
   "appType": "Live",
   "description": "Testing our Rest Service",
   "streamConfig": {
      "restURI": "http://localhost:8087/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/vhosts/_defaultVHost_/applications/testlive/streamconfiguration",
      "streamType": "live"
   },
   "securityConfig": {
      "restURI": "http://localhost:8087/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/vhosts/_defaultVHost_/applications/testlive/security",
      "secureTokenVersion": 0,
      "clientStreamWriteAccess": "*",
      "publishRequirePassword": true,
      "publishPasswordFile": "",
      "publishRTMPSecureURL": "",
      "publishIPBlackList": "",
      "publishIPWhiteList": "",
      "publishBlockDuplicateStreamNames": false,
      "publishValidEncoders": "",
      "publishAuthenticationMethod": "digest",
      "playMaximumConnections": 0,
      "playRequireSecureConnection": false,
      "secureTokenSharedSecret": "",
      "secureTokenUseTEAForRTMP": false,
      "secureTokenIncludeClientIPInHash": false,
      "secureTokenHashAlgorithm": "",
      "secureTokenQueryParametersPrefix": "",
      "secureTokenOriginSharedSecret": "",
      "playIPBlackList": "",
      "playIPWhiteList": "",
      "playAuthenticationMethod": "none"
   },
   "modules": {
      "restURI": "http://localhost:8087/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/vhosts/_defaultVHost_/applications/testlive/modules",
      "moduleList": [
         {
            "order": 0,
            "name": "base",
            "description": "Base",
            "class": "com.wowza.wms.module.ModuleCore"
         },
         {
            "order": 1,
            "name": "logging",
            "description": "Client Logging",
            "class": "com.wowza.wms.module.ModuleClientLogging"
         },
         {
            "order": 2,
            "name": "flvplayback",
            "description": "FLVPlayback",
            "class": "com.wowza.wms.module.ModuleFLVPlayback"
         },
         {
            "order": 3,
            "name": "ModuleCoreSecurity",
            "description": "Core Security Module for Applications",
            "class": "com.wowza.wms.security.ModuleCoreSecurity"
         }
      ]
   }
}'
```

Comment: PHP has a cURL extension. You can install it and use it as describe on http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php. `POST` example: http://hayageek.com/php-curl-post-get/#curl-post

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, take a look at php cURL extension.  Then check out the following example script:

```
// If you have digest auth turned on, switch this to true.
$useDigest = false;
$username = "admin";
$password = "pass";

$json = '{
   "restURI": "http://localhost:8087/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/vhosts/_defaultVHost_/applications/stackoverflow",
   "name": "stackoverflow",
   "appType": "Live",
   "description": "Testing our Rest Service",
   "streamConfig": {
      "restURI": "http://localhost:8087/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/vhosts/_defaultVHost_/applications/stackoverflow/streamconfiguration",
      "streamType": "live"
   },
   "securityConfig": {
      "restURI": "http://localhost:8087/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/vhosts/_defaultVHost_/applications/stackoverflow/security",
      "secureTokenVersion": 0,
      "clientStreamWriteAccess": "*",
      "publishRequirePassword": true,
      "publishPasswordFile": "",
      "publishRTMPSecureURL": "",
      "publishIPBlackList": "",
      "publishIPWhiteList": "",
      "publishBlockDuplicateStreamNames": false,
      "publishValidEncoders": "",
      "publishAuthenticationMethod": "digest",
      "playMaximumConnections": 0,
      "playRequireSecureConnection": false,
      "secureTokenSharedSecret": "",
      "secureTokenUseTEAForRTMP": false,
      "secureTokenIncludeClientIPInHash": false,
      "secureTokenHashAlgorithm": "",
      "secureTokenQueryParametersPrefix": "",
      "secureTokenOriginSharedSecret": "",
      "playIPBlackList": "",
      "playIPWhiteList": "",
      "playAuthenticationMethod": "none"
   },
   "modules": {
      "restURI": "http://localhost:8087/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/vhosts/_defaultVHost_/applications/stackoverflow/modules",
      "moduleList": [
         {
            "order": 0,
            "name": "base",
            "description": "Base",
            "class": "com.wowza.wms.module.ModuleCore"
         },
         {
            "order": 1,
            "name": "logging",
            "description": "Client Logging",
            "class": "com.wowza.wms.module.ModuleClientLogging"
         },
         {
            "order": 2,
            "name": "flvplayback",
            "description": "FLVPlayback",
            "class": "com.wowza.wms.module.ModuleFLVPlayback"
         },
         {
            "order": 3,
            "name": "ModuleCoreSecurity",
            "description": "Core Security Module for Applications",
            "class": "com.wowza.wms.security.ModuleCoreSecurity"
         }
      ]
   }
}';

$ch = curl_init("http://localhost:8087/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/vhosts/_defaultVHost_/applications/stackoverflow");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $json);

if($useDigest){
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_DIGEST);
}

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
    'Accept:application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'Content-type:application/json; charset=utf-8',
    'Content-Length: '.strlen($json)
));
$contents = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch); 
$response = json_decode($contents);

var_dump($response);
```

This will yield similar output to the following:

```
object(stdClass)#1 (3) {
  ["success"]=>
  bool(true)
  ["message"]=>
  string(49) "Application (stackoverflow) created successfully."
  ["data"]=>
  NULL
}
```

You can find several other [cURL examples](https://www.wowza.com/forums/content.php?739-Application-management-query-examples) that you can simply manipulate the JSON being sent along with the verb type (in this case POST) to further leverage the REST API.

An example of a GET request to retrieve your existing applications, you can remove the CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS cURL option and modify the following lines:

```
$ch = curl_init("http://localhost:8087/v2/servers/_defaultServer_/vhosts/_defaultVHost_/applications");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "GET");
```